# doesn't compile: sparkjava exception handling

Tags: java, intellij-idea, exception, spark-java

I am trying to follow the sparkjava exception handling example located here, without success: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#exception-mapping.  It appears the code they posted isn't quite right?  I was able to fix one of the posted methods so that it compiles.  The method on the documentation page which doesn't compile was:

```
get("/throwexception", (request, response) -> {
    throw new NotFoundException();
});
```

I changed to this code and it compiles:

```
    get(new Route("/throwexception") {
        @Override
        public Object handle(Request request, Response response)  {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    });
```

However, I am unable to get this method to compile.  What is wrong?  I am using java 8 and IntelliJ community edition 15.0.2 to compile.  My java module is set to language level 8.  Here is the suspect method:

```
    exception(Exception.class, (e, request, response) -> {
        //TODO: implement this after it compiles.
    });
```

Here is the error I get from the compiler:

```
Error:(83, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method exception(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Exception>,(e,request[...]->{ })
  location: class org.me.JournalController
```

To confirm that I really am using java 8, this example using a lambda expression does compile:

```
public class Lambdas {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Lambdas().start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public void start(){
        Interface f = () -> System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My maven file had sparkjava dependency listed twice.  I think my IDE automatically imported 1.1.1 for me at some point and I didn't realize it.  I had 1.1.1 and 2.3.  When I removed the outdated 1.1.1 sparkjava dependency then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The original code uses lambda expressions, you should use Java 8 to compile it.

Comment: I believe I'm using java jdk 1.8.0_66.  I can see in the project configuration this is what I have selected.  Also, my module has language level 8.  Could it be something else?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: do you have import static spark.Spark.*; at the beginning of your file?

Comment: sorry, I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: I updated the question.  I tried a class with a lambda expression and it does compile ... I suspect you're onto something ... I probably don't have spark configured correctly.  Not sure what I might be missing.  I'll add my maven code.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your throw statement into a function:

```
get("/throwexception", () -> BlowUp());

(snip)

public static void BlowUp()
{
    throw new NotFoundException();
});
```

Comment: I had that originally.  I modified to try to fix the compilation error which was caused by maven dependency problems.  Thanks for the suggestion, though ;)